# How to create executable jar file from springboot - maven application?

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, executable-jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

When I tried to create a jar file using maven plugin in eclipse, I got thus error while trying to execute that jar:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
>   get nested archive for entry
>   BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar

This seems to be a bug in 2017. Is there any solution for this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your executable jar file doesn't contain above jar file.You should build jar with dependencies.

- **Right click** project then click '**Run As**'
- **Maven Build**
- And you should type '**package**' in input area then **run**.
- /path/your/project/target/ there is your .jar file with dependencies.